# Where to find/get systemd-journal-gatewayd.service on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, systemd

It seems `systemd-journal-gatewayd` daemon was introduced in [systemd version 193](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-September/006738.html).

I'm running Debian Jessie with verison 215 of `systemd`, but do not have this daemon.

```
$ systemd --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
# systemctl start systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
Failed to start systemd-journal-gatewayd.service: Unit systemd-journal-gatewayd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

So 1. Any ideas why it's missing? and 2. Where/how can I find it?

Please note I am not super familiar with `apt` package management and even less familiar with Debian.

Answer (score 1):

See [systemd: Please add support for systemd-journal-gatewayd](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=742802)

[Fixed](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/commit/52758fa) in `systemd/224-2`.

> Add new binary package `systemd-journal-remote` with tools for sending/receiving remote journal logs: systemd-journal-{remote,upload,gatewayd}. (Closes: #742802, LP: #1480952)