# How to install systemd-journal-gatewayd

Tags: debian, systemd, apt, raspbian, systemd-journald

How do I install systemd-journal-gatewayd on a raspberry pi?
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-gatewayd.service.html

stretch

```
michael@stetch:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd
michael@stetch:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket'
michael@stetch:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.service'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.service'
michael@stetch:~ $
```

jessie

```
michael@jessie:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd
michael@jessie:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket'
michael@jessie:~ $ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'systemd-journal-gatewayd.service'
michael@jessie:~ $
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227394/where-to-find-get-systemd-journal-gatewayd-service-on-debian-jessie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the [`systemd-journal-remote`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/systemd-journal-remote) package:

On debian stretch

```
apt install systemd-journal-remote
```

On debian Jessie the `systemd-journal-remote` is available on jessie-backports

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install systemd-journal-remote
```

Start the service:

```
systemctl start systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
```

---

To install a package from Jessie-backports you should :

edit your `sources.list`

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

save then update :

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks GAD3$.  Stretch worked as advertised, but get `E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources` on Jessie.  Any ideas?  Never mind.  My bad `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main`

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  Just curious, what is the difference between the one I referred to in my comment `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main` and the one you included `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free`?  Thank you

Comment: the `main` , `contrib` and `non-free` is [explained here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Component) and [the Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG)](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines)